# Pycharm Debugger Cannot Step Into Thread Class

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

When trying to debug some code in `Pycharm`, I found that I could not step into the `threading.Thread` class. Here is  simple example to demonstrate the situation:

```
from threading import Thread


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(**kwargs) # set breakpoint at this line


MyThread()
```

In Pycharm, I set a breakpoint at the call to `super`, then do a `Run->Debug`. The execution pauses at the breakpoint as expected, but when I click on `Step Into`, it steps over the `super` instead of into it. When I use `pdb` outside of `Pycharm`, I can step into the `super` call. Is there any way to enable stepping into that call, or is this just a limitation of `Pycharm` debugging?

I am able to step into other `Python` classes, but not `Thread`.

Comment: If I recall correctly this is a known debugger limitation. I created a ticket in PyCharms' bug tracker for the responsible developer to investigate: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35261